# classList.add working only for the first time in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

I'm trying to add a className to the parent element (li) of an input whenever the input is focussed.

```
<div className="SubCategory__palette">
                <ul aria-label="Filter options">
                    {SubcategoryArraySort.map((filtersub) => (
                    
                        <li
                            key={filtersub.subCategoryId}
                            onClick={() => {
                                props.handleSubCategoryClick(filtersub.subCategoryId, datarry);
                            }}
                            id={`${filtersub.name}--li-container`}
                        >
                            <label htmlFor={filtersub.name} >
                                    {filtersub.name}
                            </label>
                            <input
                                id={filtersub.name}
                                className="SubCategory__input-style"
                                type="radio"
                                name="sub-category-pills"
                                onFocus={() => {
                                    onInputFocus(filtersub.name);
                                }}
                                onBlur={() => {
                                    onInputBlur(filtersub.name);
                                }}
                            />
                        </li> 
                        
                    ))}
                </ul> 
                </div>
```

The functions are:

```
    function onInputFocus(id: string) {
            const containerId = `${id}--li-container`;
            $('#' + `${containerId}`).addClass('subCategoryFocussed');
    }

    function onInputBlur(id: string) {
        const containerId = `${id}--li-container`;
        $('#' + `${containerId}`).removeClass('subCategoryFocussed');
    }
```

```
.subCategoryFocussed {
   outline: 2px solid blue;
}
```

**Issue**: When I navigate through the `tab` key, 1st radio button is focussed and className is added to it's parent element. Now after pressing the `arrow-keys` to navigate to other radio buttons, the className is not added to them even when they are in focussed state.

Why the classList.add only worked for the first time?

Am I missing something here??

Comment: Are you sure you actually shift the focus by navigating with the arrow keys?

Comment: @Entertain yes, radio button works that way

Comment: Did you try to track the focused element with an id and apply an additional css style/class if the tracked focus id matches the rendered li item?

Answer (score 0):

If your browser stack allows it you can achieve the same behaviour by using the `:focus-within` pseudo-class.

Instead of a class all you need is `li:focus-within { outline: 2px solid blue }`

Comment: Yes, this approach worked. Thanks.

But I'm now interested in why classList.add is not working.

Comment: The approach you were using is very JQuery like, referring to elements with classes and IDs. In React you need to think more in terms of state. In this case you could have done something like `const [activeIndex, setActiveIndex] = useState()` and `<li className={activeIndex === 0 && 'active'}><input onFocus={() => setActiveInput(index)} onBlur={() => setActiveInput(null) /></li>`. Also place your `onClick` handler on the actual input, this is an element designed to receive clicks and has the required accessibility features built in.